# Jquery Data attribute selector not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this element

```
<div class="messages selected" data-conversationId=""></div>
```

The `data-attribute` `conversationId` is set dynamically like so:

```
$(".messages").data("conversationId", conversationId);
```

I am having issues using a selector to select this element by the data attribute.

```
$(".messages[data-conversationId=4]")
```

Returns empty array. Interestingly:

```
$(".messages").data("conversationId")
```

returns `4`

What is wrong with my selector?

Comment: It gets the last one... So the last one might have the value `4`?

Comment: Attribute values must be quoted. `$('.messages[data-conversationId="4"]')`.

Comment: You are missing quotes: ```$('.messages[data-conversationId="4"]')```should work?

Comment: I think you are updating data attribute using `data()` method which just update it's property not it's attribute.... so you need to use `filter()`  or update attribute value using `attr()` method

Comment: Nope, attribute values dont have to be quoted.

Comment: Why would you expect `data-conversationId=""` to be found with a value of 4? Where are you setting it to 4?

Comment: @j08691 "The data-attribute conversationId is set dynamically"

Comment: Please add the code you're using to do that -- it's relevant

Comment: @PranavCBalan had the right answer, do you want to submit ' update attribute value using attr() method ' as an answer?

Comment: @HHHome : glad to help :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you set your dynamic attribute via jquery's .data() you will have the above problem.

However, if you set the dynamic attribute via jquery's .attr() method, you won't have this problem

Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/6dn5wjL8/8/

HTML

```
<div id="test1" class="messages selected" data-conversationId="">testContent1</div>
<div id="test2" class="messages selected" data-conversationId="">testContent2</div>
```

JS:

```
// Will work
$("#test1").attr("data-conversationId", 4)
// Will not work
$("#test2").data("conversationId", 3)


alert("With selector .messages[data-conversationId=4] I found a div with this content: "+$(".messages[data-conversationId=4]").html())

alert("With selector .messages[data-conversationId=3] I found a div with this content: "+$(".messages[data-conversationId=3]").html())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think with this statement
$('.message[data-conversationId=4]') , you are trying to select an element which has class message and who has data-conversationId as 4.

and this statement $(".message").data('conversationId'), in this example of yours would return undefined because in the markup you have mentioned it as data-conversationid=""

change the markup to data-conversationid="5" and check with the statement 
$(".message").data('conversationId'),it would return 5

Hope this helps

Comment: Again, im setting it dynamically so I can't do this in the markup

Comment: can you please include the code where you are setting it dynamically

Comment: It will helps us to understand whats happening